# Z ordering geometry

Tags: c++, c, opengl, rendering

I'm making a game that is entirely made of cubes. I notice that when I walk forward it runs lightening fast, but if I rotate the player in the opposite direction, its cripplingly slow. So what I did is ordered based on angle, but I still get some angles that are a bit slow. Here is how I did it:

I basically reverse iterate in certain angles, but how could I make it consistent, so that every angle is lightening fast, some of the straight angles like 88-92, or 178-182 are really slow (overdraw).

Thanks

```
SetPlayerPosition();


PlayerPosition.x -= 70;

PlayerPosition.y -= 20;

PlayerPosition.z -= 70;


collids.clear();
CBox* tmp;
float offset = -10;
if( Wrap(Camera.roty + offset) > 180 && Wrap(Camera.roty + offset) < 270)
{
    for(int i = 140; i > 0; --i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 40; ++j)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < 140; ++k)
            {

                tmp = GetCube(PlayerPosition.x + i, PlayerPosition.y + j, PlayerPosition.z + k);



                if(tmp != 0)
                {
                    if(frustum.sphereInFrustum(tmp->center,25) != NULL)
                    {
                        collids.push_back(tmp);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
else if(Wrap(Camera.roty + offset) > 0 && Wrap(Camera.roty + offset) < 90 )
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 140; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 40; ++j)
        {
            for(int k = 140; k > 0; --k)
            {

                tmp = GetCube(PlayerPosition.x + i, PlayerPosition.y + j, PlayerPosition.z + k);



                if(tmp != 0)
                {
                    if(frustum.sphereInFrustum(tmp->center,25) != NULL)
                    {
                        collids.push_back(tmp);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

else if(Wrap(Camera.roty + offset) > 90 && Wrap(Camera.roty + offset) < 180 )
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 140; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 40; ++j)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < 140; ++k)
            {

                tmp = GetCube(PlayerPosition.x + i, PlayerPosition.y + j, PlayerPosition.z + k);



                if(tmp != 0)
                {
                    if(frustum.sphereInFrustum(tmp->center,25) != NULL)
                    {
                        collids.push_back(tmp);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
else if (Wrap(Camera.roty + offset) > 270 && Wrap(Camera.roty + offset) < 360)
{
    for(int i = 140; i > 0; --i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 40; ++j)
        {
            for(int k = 140; k > 0; --k)
            {

                tmp = GetCube(PlayerPosition.x + i, PlayerPosition.y + j, PlayerPosition.z + k);



                if(tmp != 0)
                {
                    if(frustum.sphereInFrustum(tmp->center,25) != NULL)
                    {
                        collids.push_back(tmp);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yikes.

Without knowing what `GetCube` is doing, I can't begin to guess how it's affecting your performance, but it's pretty clear why things are slowing down so significantly. You're doing a lot of unnecessary work.

You can eliminate most of your loops simply by taking a different approach: Ignore the angle, and do more simplified tests. For any value of `i`, `j`, and `k`, do nothing if it marks a cube behind the "player." That alone will even out your framerate and simplify your loops. (You don't need four different sets of nested loops!)

Even better, use a **spatial graph** - something like an octree or kd-tree - to store instances of your cubes (or other objects), and do your intersection tests on nodes of the tree. That way, you can eliminate *huge swaths* of objects all at once that will never be inside the frustum, and improve performance significantly.